# Story about an artist named “A” whose work literally sucks his life away until he vanishes

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story in the 70s about an artist named “A”, whose work literally sucked his life away.

He wasted away with each new piece until he vanished.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)